# Why is it not possible to bypass SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE on serveral browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, certificate

I have tried to open https://utox.io which has right now the following error:

- SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE (FireFox)
- NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID (Chrome)
- DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_DATE_INVALID (Internet Explorer)

"http**s**://" is forced by a redirect, so it is not possible to open it via "http://".

I don't want to submit any information there to this website (reading only), so actually I don't care about encryption in this case.

Why is it not possible to just click on a "I know the risk, go ahead" button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible because browsers have become more strict about certificates.
This website uses an elapsed certificate by Let's Encrypt, with which it's not
possible to establish an https connection, so it's blocked.

To bypass this restriction, create a Chrome shortcut and add to it the parameter
`--ignore-certificate-errors`. Chrome will give a warning on starting,
but will open the website.

I remark that this workaround might also stop working in the future.

Comment: Why is it then possible to go around a self-signed certificate warning (add exception), what is actually more risky?

Comment: This is an undocumented parameter, to use at your own risk. To use, you should be sure that this website is legit. Do not use this parameter in your regular work, only for accessing special websites.

Comment: I mean, independent from your workaround, why is it in general at all browser possible to go around a self-signed certificate warning (add exception, go ahead click), what is actually more risky, but you cannot go around an outdated cert?

Comment: The add exception option will also get harder and harder to use. For this website, neither Chrome nor Firefox gave me this option at all.

Comment: No, you can establish an HTTPS connection with an expired certificate just fine, you simply lose some of the security guarantees.

Comment: Also, the reason the option isn't available is probably because the site uses HSTS.  Without that, Chrome should either try to fall back to unencrypted HTTP, or at least offer the option of ignoring the certificate error.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: I have checked the profile, and there was no problem with HSTS, this was my first ever visit to that site.

Comment: @harrymc My point was that Chrome may be a bit pickier about not letting you access the site with an invalid certificate because the site itself declares a requirement for encryption using HSTS (and it appears to be in the HSTS preload list, which means that Chrome already knew it used HSTS before you even tried to connect).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: Firefox was equally picky. Both browsers seem to use the same policy, Firefox following Chrome.

Comment: @harrymc It's essentially what HSTS is asking for though, given that it indicates that users shouldn't be accessing the site over an insecure channel, and an invalid certificate means you don't have any security guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, this works in Chrome/Canary:

```
open -na "Google Chrome Canary" --args --ignore-certificate-errors "https://cryptobin.co"
```